# AngularJS to Angular 2 routing issues

Tags: angular

In angularJS if for example I have 2 pages (home.html and away.html) as application modules in an enterprise, I can build route for each page independent of the other (eg for home we can have route for bedroom, chamber, hall, etc and for away we can have route for park, street, etc). The essence is that the customer using home service should not have access to away page.

How can that be done in angular 2???

Comment: is what you want angular routes, nested routes and routes guard?

Comment: Add route guards to your route... Refer here.. https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Answer (score 0):

You can guard off specific routes. you can create a GuardService for that. Here's a snippet of mine:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn().map(success => {
      if (success === false) {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
      return success;
    });
  }
}
```

and you can use this in your route:

```
{ path: 'cockpit', component: CockpitComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }
```

Comment: Will try it and see, I am quite new to angular2 though